# Why can I not run docker and virtualbox

Tags: docker, android-studio, virtualbox

I had run into a problem, I want to run Virtualbox on my main machine and also run docker and android studio.

The problem is that Android sudio and docker need Hyper-v to be enabled to run while Virtualbox need Hyper-v to be disabled to run a machine.

I am running Windows 10 with a ryzen cpu. Any sugestion ?

Comment: You could use Docker Toolbox, which is based on VirtualBox and does not require HyperV, so that would at least solve one issue. For the Android Studio issue, no idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Docker Toolbox](https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/toolbox_install_windows/) to run a docker host inside Virtualbox